# Primefaces' ckEditor not able to pass full contents in server side for pdf download processing

Tags: primefaces, ckeditor

Been having some trouble on primefaces plugin ckeditor_config: not all contents are being passed from client to server side: I even compared both the raw content data from client and the one being processed by server and it almost cut in half interms of content, meaning second half of contents are missing .

Config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.fullPage = true;//允许包含html标签
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.font_names ="MingLiU_HKSCS;Arial;";
    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
    config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = true;
    //屏蔽换行符<br>
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    //屏蔽段落<p>
    config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
    config.autoUpdateElement = true;
    config.fillEmptyBlocks=false;
    config.disableObjectResizing = true;
    config.font_defaultLabel = 'MingLiU_HKSCS';
    config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '10px';
    config.toolbar = [
            ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Font','FontSize']
            ];
    
    config.font_style =
    {
    element : 'span',
    styles : { 'font-family' : 'MingLiU_HKSCS' },
    overrides : [ { element : 'font', attributes : { 'face' : null } } ]
    };
};
```

xhtml:

```
    <p:panelGrid style="width:595px;">
                    <p:row>
                      <p:column>
                           <pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{docxEditorUi.htmlReport}" width="850" height="500" escape="true" 
                                        customConfig="#{request.contextPath}/resources/tci/js/ckeditor_config.js">
                            <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this editForm:editor" />
                            <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{docxEditorUi.saveListener}"/>
                           </pe:ckEditor>
                      </p:column>
                      </p:row>
                      <p:row>
                      <p:column style="float:right;">
                          <p:commandButton id="download" update="@form"
                               value="Download" ajax="false"
                               onclick="javascript:getUpdatedHtmlEditor();">
                               <p:fileDownload value="#{docxEditorUi.getDownloadFile()}" />
                           </p:commandButton>
                           <p:commandButton id="close" value="Close" >
                                 <p:ajax listener="#{docxEditorUi.closeScreen}"/>
                           </p:commandButton>
                      </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                  </p:panelGrid>

Now the client side html string I was able to retrieve it in full and pass it to hidden textare temporaryly:



<html>
<body style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:10pt; background:#ffffff" class="cke_editable 
       .........COMPLETE CONTENTS HERE 
</body>
</html>
```

However when debugged in server side / java, I only get a portion of it, in return some of the updated contents are not being captured after download. I saw from other posts/threads that it could be the limit of post request and tried to add maxPostSize in my server.xml (websphere) but could'nt find where should I put it or even this is a real limitation on the server itself... our goal is for whatever content update from the editor, it should be passed to the server for further processing and be able to render it in downloaded pdf document.

Comment: To me it definitely sounds like a POST size limit is preventing over a certain size if its only getting part of the text.

Comment: yes , totally agree but I cannot seem to find any workaround to set it in my server, using websphere v8.